Start kwin_wayland over ssh on remote TTY
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Debian with a small HDMI display connected. I want to log in to it via SSH, and from the command line, start a kwin_wayland display, or some other Wayland-based display server, on a remote TTY, that is, on the Raspberry Pi, such as TTY4. Then, I want to launch an application, such as konsole, and switch to the TTY so it displays on the local screen. Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible. Sorry for this snide remark, but I think you need to read [ask]. Generally, yes/no questions are often useless.

As Ulrich said -- a question about a specific technical problem you encountered while trying to do this yourself would be more clearly inside our topicality guidelines, and generally better received. (And if that problem is more configuration- or usage-centric than programming-centric in nature, it probably belongs on [unix.se] rather than here... or on [raspberrypi.se] if the details are somehow RPi-specific -- say, if it can't be reproduced on non-Raspbian distros).

Sorry for posing the question unclearly and in the wrong forum. I shall find the appropriate forum and reformulate; thanks for the suggestions, @CharlesDuffy and Ulrich Eckhardt!
